# Qt и dll, ошибка: file not recognized: File format not recognized в чем суть и как исправить если нет исходников?

Tags: c++, qt, dll, mingw

Добрый день!

Разработка ведется: Qt 5.7.0 + MinGW 5.3.0 (32-bit) + Qt Creator 4.0.2, Win7.

Заинтересовала суть ошибки "file not recognized: File format not recognized" и как с ней бороться, в случае если нет исходников библиотеки.

Столкнулся с такой ошибкой при подключение [wsp32.dll](http://caxapa.ru/lib/wake/dn_wake/wusource.zip) - реализация протокола wake для работы с прибором по rs232 (при подключение - LIBS += -lwsp32 в pro файле, в комплекте с dll идет .lib).

P.S. В конкретном случае - доступны исходники библиотеки, и с некоторыми изменениями в итоге затащу в проект как отдельные .cpp + .h, но хотелось бы понять причины ошибки и альтернативные пути исправления.

[Zip архив с тестовым qt проектом с подключением wsp32](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_CFj5kQhpSAaXI3eGhNbG9JQm8).

Comment: Я где-то при загадочных обстоятельствах краем уха слышал что есть странная ошибка. Давайте подумаем про её суть? Нет, это не правильный вопрос. Нужно показать: 1. Какая конкретно функция/операция вызывает ошибку. 2. Желательно Цепочка Стек-фрейма вызовов ошибки. 3.Фрагмент кода где возникла ошибка.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на архив с qt проектом, где подключается библиотека и вызывается обозначенная ошибка. Фрагмент кода - LIBS += -lwsp32 в test.pro файле. Ошибка на уровне сборки, так что стека-фрейма не получится.

Comment: @Geek16bits Вы извините, но никто не будет качать ваш архив разбираться с проектом, лучше включите исходники прямо в текст вопроса. Прежде всего нужно место в программе при работе которого появляется ошибка, а также описание что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: @Cerbo это понимаю, что не будут :) нет ни какого исходного кода, просто когда подключаем библиотеку к пустому проекту, сразу при сборке ошибка. Добавил уточнение в вопрос.

Comment: @Geek16bits, так ошибку кто выдаёт - линкер? И к чему относится секция `LIBS` с ключом `-lwsp32`. Если к линкеру, то объясните смысл попытки прилинковать dll как статическую библиотеку?

Comment: Эта библиотека (wsp32.lib) собрана C++Builder'ом. В настоящее время не существует стандарта на бинарные библиотеки. У всех компиляторов они имеет разный формат. Поэтому тут два пути: либо собирать библиотеку под gcc (libwsp32.a), либо включать её исходники в полном объёме в ваш проект.

Comment: @Embedder понял. Получается, что при отсутствие исходников, такой библиотекой воспользоваться не удастся?

Comment: @Geek16bits, ну если отказаться от gcc+Qt и использовать C++Builder, то удастся.

Comment: @Embedder, там же dll.

Comment: @PinkTux, dll - это для времени выполнения (сама реализация функционала), а библиотека (lib или a) нужна для "связывания" на этапе сборки. Реального функционала там нет.

Comment: @Embedder, ничего не понял. Откуда информация что в Qt для подключения к проекту DLL нужно какое-то дополнительное связывание со статическими либами?

Comment: @PinkTux, a Qt тут не при чём. Это всё прерогатива компилятора. Ведь из одного набора исходников можно собрать как статическую библиотеку, так и динамическую. В первом случаи получим файл, ну например: libtest_s.a, в котором будет полная реализация функционала. Во втором случаи, у нас будет два файла  test.dll и libtest.a. Dll ,будет содержать реализацию функционала, а файл библиотеки только информацию для компилятора о экспортируемых функциях из этой dll.

Comment: Хотя, как ниже написал **gdg**, экспортировать функции можно и напрямую. Об этом варианте, я честно говоря подзабыл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если библиотека экспортирует только C - функции, просто линкуйтесь к самой dll, а не к lib. GCC справится.